# How to insert a set of values that are passed to a function in vector that is already declared

Tags: c++

Lets consider this c++ code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
void setTipp(int& n1, int& n2, int& n3, int& n4, int& n5, int& n6) {
    //insert all 6 elements inside vector 
    //but not like v.pushback(n1); etc
    //also not like v.resize(6); v[0]=n1; etc
}
```

is there a way to insert all 6 elements inside vector v automatically even if vector v has already been decalred.

I would like to insert values inside v like v{n1,n2....n6}; or like

```
for (int i=0; i<=6;i++){
//v.pusback(n1);pushback(n2) etc.
//or v[i]=n1....n6;  
}
```

is there a way to do this without creating a new vector or array inside the function "setTipp"

without doing something like this:

```
void setTipp(int& n1, int& n2, int& n3, int& n4, int& n5, int& n6) {
 std::vector<int> tmp{n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6};
 v=tmp;
}
```

Comment: Do you require there to be exactly six parameters passed, or do you just want to insert "all the parameters"?

Comment: the requirements are rather foggy, why do you want to push elements to a vector without pushing elements to a vector?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Can you give a context on why would you want to have such function?

Comment: Hi, i would like to push all parameters inside a vector 6 is just an example

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? I would like to push all values inside vector without hardcoding it

Comment: Hi, an example of precisely what? These values must come from somewhere, what would a typical call look like? Do you really have X separate variables somewhere? In that case, why not group them into an array in the first place?

Comment: Hi, an example of precisely what? These values must come from somewhere, what would a typical call look like? Do you really have X separate variables somewhere? In that case why not grouping them into an array? its a function that takes numbers from a player that is playing lotto game for example 6 out of 49 etc. Its a member function of class Tipp and these numbers are stored inside a private vector of class tipp

Comment: " its a function that takes numbers from a player that is playing lotto game for example 6 out of 49 etc." .. which brings us back to: why does the function take seperate parameters in the first place? You can "automatically" insert without pushing individual numbers if the function takes an array as parameter (see Jarods answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use initializer_list:

```
std::vector<int> v;
void setTipp(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6) {
    for (int i : {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

But I would probably change signature to something like:

```
void setTipp(const std::array<int, 6>& a) {
    v.insert(v.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
}
```

so changing call from:

```
setTipp(4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42);
```

to

```
setTipp({{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42}});
```

Comment: beautiful, thanks i completely forgot about for each loop

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to insert values inside v like v{n1,n2....n6};

You can try:

```
int arr[] = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6};
v.insert(std::end(v), std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Comment: Preferably use `std::end(arr)`.

Comment: Instead of `arr + 6`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to insert an entire range `r` at once, e.g.:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
v.insert(v.end(), begin(r), end(r));
```

For instance, `v` and `r` can be:

```
std::vector<int> v;
const int r[] = {3, 4, 5};
```

The advantage of using [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) through ADL is that it will work with any container that implements the appropriate operations, and also with arrays.

Comment: Hmm, I understood that the function interface is given. I do think that range insert is the best choice, though.

Comment: @JensFinkhaeuser Yeah, I tried to show the generic way of doing it, which can be applied to basically any situation, including OP's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function template with variadic paramter pack to automatically add all arguments - no matter how many - into the vector:

```
template<class... N>
void setTipp(N&... n)
{
    (v.push_back(n), ...);
}
```

That said, given your further description of the case in comments, it makes little sense to pass the arguments as separate variables. You an array instead.

Comment: @JeJo doesn't really matter whether we take a forwarding reference since we are using integers. Probably would make more sense to pass by value, but I kept the references in order to minimise differences to the original code. Without an actual use case, it's not possible to say what would be the best choice; this is just a minimal demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::apply](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) with [std::make_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple), and *apply* `push_back` to each tuple value this way. Unfortunately, you'd need to use [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) as well, making the entire exercise a little heavy for my taste.

```cpp
// Given:
vec_type my_vec;

// Do:
std::apply(
  std::bind(my_vec, &vec_type::push_back, _1),
  std::make_tuple(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6)
);
```

[Might not compile, just demonstrating the idea.]

- you still invoke `push_back` multiple times, which isn't really an optimization.
- a `std::tuple` is only somewhat more lightweight than a `std::vector`, and probably not the best choice at large numbers of parameters.